# TableView Header Text Issue

Tags: swift, uitableview, header, label

i have a bit of a problem with spacing as seen here : (Excuse my bad drawing skills :\ )

[image: Bad Drawing Example + Spacing Issue]

Can anyone tell me how to fix this spacing issue ? i can't find a solution to it ... Here is my code:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        let headerText = UILabel()
        headerText.textColor = UIColor.darkGrayColor()
        switch section{
        case 0:
            headerText.textAlignment = .Right
            headerText.text = "הבר המועדף עליכם חסר? שתפו אותנו ונוסיף"
        case 1:
            headerText.textAlignment = .Right
            headerText.text = "יש לכם רעיון לשיפור האפליקציה? שתפו אותנו :)"
        default:
            headerText.textAlignment = .Right
            headerText.text = ""
        }
        //Any Other Customizations

        return headerText
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement the `heightForHeaderInSection` delegate method and return the desired height.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 35.0//write here your desired value. This will be your table's header height
}
```